# Unable to locate text inside multiple spans in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, html, testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I am fairly new to Selenium for C#, and I am trying to locate the error message for a form when a password is not typed in, but the NUnit test is failing. Furthermore I don't know XML so cannot use XPath. Here is what I got so far:

```
   [Test]
    public void TheNoPasswordTest()
    {
        selenium.Open("/Dashboards/Login")
        selenium.Type("id=Username", "HERCULES\\FakeUsername");
        selenium.Type("id=Password", "");
        selenium.Click("css=input.btn.login-button");
        var PasswordClass = firefox.FindElementByClassName("login-field-error field-validation-error");
        var span = firefox.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[for='Password']"));
        Assert.AreEqual("The Password field is required",span.Text);

    }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
 <div>
        <span class="login-field-error field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true">
            <span for="Password" class>
               :: before
               "The Password field is required."
            </span>
     </span>
    <div>
```

Comment: Please clarify, with your tags, if you are using [tag:selenium-rc] or [tag:selenium-webdriver]. They are not the same!

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the compound classes, meaning multiple classes which Selenium does not support at this moment. try CssSelector mentioned below

```
.login-field-error.field-validation-error
```

> Test

```
[Test]
public void TheNoPasswordTest()
{
    selenium.Open("/Dashboards/Login");
    selenium.Type("id=Username", "HERCULES\\FakeUsername");
    selenium.Type("id=Password", "");
    selenium.Click("css=input.btn.login-button");
    var PasswordClass = firefox.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".login-field-error.field-validation-error"));

    Assert.IsTrue(PasswordClass.Text.Contains("The Password field is required"));
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Selenium RC, without using the Web Driver. I just did the NUnit test with this and got the error message "OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Unable to locate element: ("method" :"css selector", "selector":"login-field-error.field-validation-error").  Furthermore the specific div outlined above is inside another <div> (no id) and a <form>, does that make a difference?

Comment: @Shashank While you can do most things with Selenium RC, I would encourage you to get comfortable with WebDriver. The RC API is deprecated, and receiving no updates or attention from the Selenium project team.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first wait for the element to appear and the fetch the text.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
IWebElement span = wait.Until(
ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//span[@for='Password']")));
Assert.AreEqual("The Password field is required",span.Text);
```

I suggest you read about writing Xpaths. Its pretty easy :)

Comment: Hi ! What is _driver exactly ? Is it a IWebDriver object ?

Comment: Yes. It is your driver instance.

Comment: I suspect OP is using [tag:Selenium-RC], your answer using [tag:selenium-webdriver] will not work for him.